# TX file extension for shared libraries?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, shared-libraries

I have downloaded and built Teigha SDK in Ubuntu 12.04. When I built Teigha SDK, lots of .tx files are generated. I'm not sure what exactly they are. From the messages on command prompt, it seemed like another extension to shared libraries. In that case, how .tx files different from .so files?

Comment: +1 I had the same question. FYI: http://www.opendesign.com/guestfiles/tx_sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I built Teigha SDK, lots of .tx files are generated. I'm not sure what exactly they are.

Run `file *.tx`; it will likely tell you what they are.

> how .tx files different from .so files

They have different letters in the end :-)

On UNIX, file extension rarely matters. You can generally copy `foo.o` to `foo.os` or `foo.xyz`, and it would still work fine.

That said, when you use `gcc main.c -lfoo`, the linker will search for `libfoo.so`, but not for `libfoo.tx`, so sometimes the extension does matter.

Comment: Maybe they are intended to be `dlopen()`'ed (plugins?), and they renamed them so you do not link them by accident.

Comment: @Employed Russian They are actually dynamic shared libraries only. I had to rename some of the extensions to link to them.